# SQL script: spooling user commit

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to send sql script files to customers. According to the results the customer should commit or rollback and return the spool file. How can I log into the spool file if the customer did commit or rollback ?

Many thanks!

Comment: You'd see a commit, rollback or exit (if they're using SQL\*Pus) in the spool output; but if they do `spool of` first there's nothing you can do. What is the purpose of this, and how are they deciding whether to commit? If you want/expect them to rollback if there are errors reported then using `whenever sqlerror` might be safer, assuming the script only has DML of course.

Comment: The 'whenever sqlerror' is used,  but sometimes customer forget to commit even if he is prompted to do that, or recognize that entered improper input for substitution variable thus should it rollbacked. I have only the spoolfile to check what he really did...

Comment: how have you coded the decision point - the conditional commit/rollback?

Comment: A sqlplus scripts could always be hacked to do whatever they want. The spool file should indicate a commit or rollback if you have "SET  FEEDBACK ON". The only way to be sure is to have a DISCONNECT at the end of your script, then ask the user to run a second script which reports on the changes in a way that helps you identify if changes were committed, or have a script called report.sql, which is run before and after in separate session - if they rolled back the before and after reports should be the same.